# Import data from SQL Server database to CSV using Powershell

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell

Can anybody help me to rectify the error in the below script? The error generated is

> Exception calling "Fill" with "1" argument(s): "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Loc
>   ating Server/Instance Specified)" At SQLConnection.Ps1:11 char:17 + $SqlAdapter.Fill <<<< ($DataSet)
>
> - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
> - FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException

Script:

```
$SQLServer = "SQC1S02.domain.net\sqlvs06"
$SQLDBName = "User_prd"
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $SQLServer; Database =    $SQLDBName; User ID= Domain\User9; Password= Password@123" 
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = 'StoredProcName'
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection 
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd 
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet) 
$DataSet.Tables[0] | out-file "Output.csv"
$SqlConnection.Close()
```

Comment: Not sure if this is important, but I have always only seen - and used myself - `"uid=...;pwd=..."` in the connection string.

Answer (score 0):

```
$SQLServer   = "SQC1S02.domain.net\sqlvs06"
$SQLDBName   = "User_prd"
$user        = "Domain\UserName"
$pwd         = "Password"
$extractFile = "Output.csv"
$SQLDBQuery  = "SELECT * FROM SQLTableName"

$connectionTemplate = "Data Source={0};uid=$user;pwd=$pwd;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog={1};"
$connectionString = [string]::Format($connectionTemplate, $SQLServer, $SQLDBName)
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString
$command = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$command.CommandText = $SQLDBQuery
$command.Connection = $connection
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $command
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$connection.Close()
$DataSet.Tables[0] | Export-Csv $extractFile -notypeinformation
```